# Hadoop - look for matching names in two customer lists

Tags: hadoop, merge, match

I have two lists of people from different events; I would like to look for matching names of people amongst those lists, as well as matching companies.  I understand that potentially there will be people with the same name in each list that are not the same people, but it will help to find the matches.

**First List Example**:
Name, Company, Title
John Doe, ACME Corporation, Elephant Trainer
Jane Smith, ACME Corporation, CEO
John Smith, Widgets-R-Us, Janitor
+10,000's of rows

**Second List Example:**
Name, Company
Fred Smith, ACME Corporation
John Smith, Widgets-R-Us
John Smith, Company XYZ
Jane Smith, Company XYZ
+10,000's of rows

**Desired Output**
Matching Names:
John Smith
Jane Smith

Matching Companies:
ACME Corporation
Widgets-R-Us

I am running it in an AWS environment, and new to Hadoop.  Any programming language is fine.  I know how to do this in Excel, but want to be able to scale this over time with more lists of names (each in their own CSV file).

Comment: What have you tried? You cant exactly ask people on SO to build an entire hadoop application for you - give it a shot yourself and when and if you encounter a concrete issue along the way, come back and we'll be happy to help. I'd suggest trying the hadoop word count tutorial in java to get started.

Comment: Thank you.  I have used AWS sample word count.  I merged the two lists into one file without the other columns, and removed all spaces from the names (looked like FirstnameLastName).  This gave me a count of the names that occur most often, which was close enough to get the top names and do a manual search afterwords.
I had trouble figuring out how to tweak the word count sample, which I think I just need some more digging to understand all its pieces.  Once I get a sandbox of it working, I am guessing I will be able to play around with the rest.  Thank you.

Comment: Does anyone have a good link to a way you can go from the AWS sample wordcount model to having the code reside in a place where you can modify it?  Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You need a Mapper implementation in which you emit the Name and Company Name as Text and IntWritable.
`protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    /*Some logic to derive the person name or the Company name.*/
    String name = value.split(',')[0];
    context.write(new Text(value),new IntWritable(1));
}`

The implementation of the reduce method in Reducer would be something similar to
`public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    int count = 1;
    for(IntWritable val: values){count++;}
    //You would all the unique names with no of times it is repeated.
    context.write(key,new IntWritable(count));
}`
Hope this helps.